# Having problems refreshing express page

Tags: javascript, express

I seem to be having some problem getting a page to refresh. I fill out a form on a HTML page, which then posts to an API on a different service through the Node RequestJS module. After the post is sent, the other service conducts some jobs on it's own, and I use a get request to retrive the ID of the job done.

Once I have this ID, I use it to launch another get request, getting the logs for the job done. Ofcourse the logs are still beeing populated at that point so I want a function to refresh the webpage which is a simple expressjs served page, and not a real html, untill it gets the message that the log is complete.

My main problem now however is to get the refresh itself to actually work.

The code in my **main.js** ( connected to the HTML page )

```
request({
    url: 'http://'+host+'/hwChange',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: jSON
})
setTimeout(function(){
    request({
        url: 'http://'+host+'/lastWF',
        method: "GET",
    })    
}, 1000)
setTimeout(function(){location.href='/log'}, 2000)
timer = 2000
for ( i=0;i<30;i++){
    timer = timer+2000
    setTimeout(function(){
        request({
            url: 'http://'+host+'/log',
            method: "GET"
        })
    },timer)
}
```

And the Code in my **expressjs** ( server side )

```
app.post('/hwChange', jsonParser, function (req,res) {
   if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(500)
   request({
      url: 'https://'+user+':'+pass+'@orcprod.adeo.no:443/vco/api/workflows/9edb9c28-2e71-4d41-a789-f7d94ee4128a/executions',
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
         "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
   }, function (error, response, body){
         console.log(response)
   })
})

app.get('/lastWF', function (req,res){
   request.get('https://'+user+':'+pass+'@orcprod.adeo.no:443/vco/api/workflows/9edb9c28-2e71-4d41-a789-f7d94ee4128a/executions', function (error, response, body){
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         //console.log(body)
      }   
      var newest = JSON.parse(body)
      newest = newest.relations.link

      var arr = []
      for (var i = newest.length - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
         var now = newest[i].attributes[1].value
         arr.push(new Date(now))
      }
      var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, arr))

      for (var i = newest.length - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
         var now = newest[i].attributes[1].value
         if ( new Date(now).getTime() == maxDate.getTime() ) {
            WFid = newest[i].attributes[0].value
         }
      }
         res.end("<BR><BR>All done!")
   })
})         

app.get('/log', function (req, res) {
   request.get('https://'+user+':'+pass+'@orcprod.adeo.no:443/vco/api/workflows/9edb9c28-2e71-4d41-a789-f7d94ee4128a/executions/'+WFid+'/logs', function (error, response, body){
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         //console.log(body)
      }
      var logs = JSON.parse(body)
      for ( i = logs.logs.length -1 ; i>=0; i-- ){ 
         res.write(logs.logs[i].entry["short-description"]+"<BR>")
      }
      res.end("Done "+WFid)
   })
})
```

I've tried using location.reload in main.js, as well as location = location.href, but it does not seem to work. I think it's cause of the refresh happing too fast so I tried to slow it down with a loop.

In the code I've posted here I think my timed refresh loop failes cause of the location.href just above it.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using res.render With JADE in order to insert a meta tag into the webpage if the last Message of the log had not been recived. And removing the meta tag if it had. This had the desired effect. Once loading /log, it now updates the page by itself every 2 seconds untill the last log Message comes along and the updates stop.